# Return element type

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is it possible to return the element type? I would like to add the style of a class to HTML5 objects without the class attribute.

```
   <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>My page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                Hello World
            </header>
            <section>
                Another object
            </section>
        </body>
        <!-- jQuery if need be -->
        <script>
            $("body>*").each(function(){
                alert($(this).object());
                // Would alert "header" and "section"
            });
        </section>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName):

```
$("body>*").each(function(){
     alert(this.tagName);                
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MLc8w/)